# Cascading "@Any" relationships

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a column in an entity defined like this:

```
@Any(metaColumn=@Column(name="index_type"),fetch=FetchType.EAGER,optional=false)
@AnyMetaDef(idType="java.util.UUID", metaType="string", metaValues={
    @MetaValue(targetEntity=LocalPodcast.class, value="Local"),
    @MetaValue(targetEntity=RSSPodcast.class, value="RSS")
})
@JoinColumn(name="index_id",columnDefinition="CHAR(36)")
private PodcastIndex index;
```

When I attempt to persist values of this entity type, the associated index is not persisted.  I would like this to happen automatically.  With other relationships, I've usually used `cascade=CascadeType.ALL` in the annotation defining the relationship, but there isn't a cascade field in the `@Any` annotation.  How can I make this relationship automatically cascade?  I'm using Hibernate 5.

Comment: I think only way is we have to add annotation   `@Cascade( org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL )` .

Comment: @soorapadman - ah, I'd never noticed that there was a separate annotation for defining cascading.  yes, that'd be the way of doing it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is is a separate annotation for `cascading`. So You can Use

```
@Cascade( org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL )
```